# Что за программа на скриншоте?

Tags: unity3d, 3d, 3dsmax

Что за программа на скриншоте? Кто знает?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может быть у unity нечто подобное быть? типо редактор уровней выступает сама unity3d? просто некогда не работал с таким... может кто ответить?

Comment: может "hammer" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего это - Valve hammer Editor

Comment: может быть у unity нечто подобное быть? типо редактор уровнем выступает сама unity3d? просто некогда не работал с таким.